# Can't get out of airplane mode: option is greyed out

Tags: airplane-mode

When I go to bed, I usually put my Samsung Galaxy Ace in airplane mode to use it as an alarm clock/music player, while saving battery. I can enter that mode successfully.

However, after I enter that mode, sometimes I can't leave that mode since the option (the second one in the list) is greyed out: I have to reboot. Any ideas?

[image: What I see]

I'm using Android 2.3.4 and my phone is rooted.

Comment: If you want to go in offline mode, why does title say, `get out of offline mode`?

Comment: @SachinShekhar, I am in offline mode but I can't get out of it. Editing my question to clarify

Comment: Offline mode? You mean airplane mode?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik exactly ("airplane mode" was translated as "offline mode" in Portuguese). Editing my question.

Comment: Can you paste your `Logcat` here..

Comment: @SachinShekhar I will do this when I am able to reproduce the problem (it's completely random).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've occasionally seen this too, and at completely random times. Worse, I've had it happen on both my old Droid and my new Galaxy Nexus. I think it's just a hard-to-find bug in Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you either go to airplane mode each night, you might want to try out some automating app like [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic) (free) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (~EUR 5) which could switch on airplane mode at night, and automatically switch it off in the morning. This way you do not get stuck with a grayed-out menu item -- and in case you do and need to get out of it, you may just need to play with some profile in this app.

Another alternative would be using some toggle-switcher (e.g. [Elixier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) or [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc)), which provide you with widgets to switch airplane mode and more.

Also, on many Android devices, there's a pre-installed widget available which usually also includes airplane mode -- mostly called something like "Power Widget" or "Energy Widget"; just check the lists of widgets available to be added on your device.

Answer (score -1):

Try getting out of off-line mode while your phone is charging. If that always works the battery might grow old.

Comment: I have the same problem on a brand new Samsung Sidekick 4G, so I would think the battery is not at fault.

Comment: My Galaxy Ace is not old, either (I have had it for about 45 days), so I don't think the battery is problem.

Comment: Well, did you try putting it in and out of offline mode right after restart? I mean without having any applications open? Maybe one of them is in conflict especially since it's rooted.

Comment: After restart it always works; this only happen after the phone has been in use for a while.

Comment: Could be a glitch in 2.3.4 where Airplane mode takes the wakelock and prevents it from being released..